# Cosume rest service in erlang

Tags: rest, erlang

Hey I am trying to consume an rest service in erlang,

The module i have written looks something like this.

But its throwing some `issues.Any` idea if I am missing something

```
-module(mod_rest_casaandra).
-author("root").

%% API
-export([get_keywords/0]).
-define(BASE_URL, "http://localhost:8080/users").

get_keywords()->
Header ="",
ContentType = "application/json",
Body = "",
Method=get,
HTTPOptions=[],
Options=[],

URL = ?BASE_URL,
R =httpc:request(Method, {URL,Header}, HTTPOptions, Options).
```

Comment: _But its throwing some issues._ What issues ?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run requests `httpc` requires `inets` application started. I suspect that you didn't start it before running your request. The example below works fine:

```
application:start(inets),
httpc:request(get, {"http://google.com", []}, [], []).
```

Besides pay attention to the `Headers` (in your example it is `Header`). It is defined as

```
headers()        = [header()]
header()         = {field(), value()}
field()          = string()
value()          = string()
```

But you use `""` for it. It will work in this case because actually `""` is equal to `[]`, however be careful - you can't use something like

```
Header = "Content-Type: text/plain"
```

here.